# Satisfying one simple inequality

Tags: inequality

I have the following inequality $$t^2 + 2t(B-1) \leq M/2.$$

Now I know that $t:=\sqrt{M/2+B^2}-B$ will satisfy it, I don't quite understand how the author came up with this definition of $t$.

How can one derive the above definition of $t$ from the inequality? I'm wondering why the author defined $t$ this way? 
If someone asked you to define $t$ such that the inequality is satisfied, how would you answer?

Comment: Hmm, if you replace $B$ in the definition of $t$ by $B-1$, then RHS = LHS.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the inequality 
$$t^2+2t(B-1)-\frac{M}{2}\leq 0,$$
we must first solve $t^2+2t(B-1)-\frac{M}{2}= 0$. This has solutions 
$$t=\frac{2(1-B)\pm\sqrt{4(B-1)^2+2M}}{2}=1-B\pm\sqrt{(B-1)^2+M/2}\,.$$
The solution to the inequality is therefore
$$1-B-\sqrt{(B-1)^2+M/2}\leq t \leq 1-B+\sqrt{(B-1)^2+M/2}\,.$$

However, the given value of $t$ only lies in this interval if $M>0$. This is because
$$\begin{aligned}
\left(\sqrt{M/2+B^2}-B\right)^2 +2\left(\sqrt{M/2+B^2}-B\right)(B-1)
&=\frac{M}{2}+2B-2\sqrt{M/2+B^2}\\
&\leq \frac{M}{2} \text{ only if } M>0 \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I understand that the definition of $t$ satisfies the inequality. I'm wondering why the author defined $t$ this way? If I asked you to define $t$ such that the inequality is satisfied, how would you approach this problem?

Comment: I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $t > 0$,
$$
t^2 + 2t(B-1) \leq t^2 + 2tB.
$$
And if latter simply equals to $M/2$, by solving quadratic equation we get that value, $\sqrt{B^2 + M/2} - B$. 
Note that's true only for $M > 0$.

Comment: For $M > 0$ you can also pick $t=0$.